# Dual boot menu doesn't show up after disassembling and reassembling laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 1 year ago. It was working fine. Recently my laptop(Dell inspiron)'s hinge had an issue. So I gave it for repair in a nearby store. He said that he had just dismantled, fixed the hinge and again reassembled the lappy. But now grub doesn't show up. It directly enters Windows 10. Someone please help me get grub again.

Comment: Can you see the Ubuntu partition when you use the appropriate tools (like Disk Management) in Windows 10?